# Magento 2 to avoid special price for b2b customer

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

I have used magento 2.3.1 enterprise edition.

I need to restrict the special price for b2b customers ( either to all the b2b customers or specific customer groups).

But for B2C customers, I need to allow the special price.

Thanks in advance.